# How to run a MongoDB native query in Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Ok, I'd like to query MongoID to check one parameter agains another. Imagine I have `start_date` and `end_date` as properties of my Model. I'd like to query Mongoid like so:

```
Model.where(start_date > end_date)
```

So how can I do that? If I were to use MongoDB console, I'd do something like (untested):

```
db.collection.find({$where: "this.end_date > this.start_date"}).count()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Model.collection.find('$where' => 'this.end_date > this.start_date')` or in Mongoid 3 as `Model.where('this.end_date > this.start_date')`?

Comment: No, I haven't and once I done now, it works. Do you want to add as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
Model.collection.find('$where' => 'this.end_date > this.start_date')
```

or in Mongoid 3 as

```
Model.where('this.end_date > this.start_date')
```